# Maze: Emoji Portals

Tags: visual, mazes, emoji, network

This is a more classic style of maze that I've been working on.
Each emoji is twinned on the subsequent level, and appears in the same co-ordinate on that level.
Your Mission: get from START to EXIT.
There is only one route.
All portals, cells, and corridors are visited maximum once.
Portals are always in adjacent levels.

Order of levels...

> zig-zag. start top-left, go down, then right, up, right, then down, ending up at the bottom-right.

[image: Emoji Portal Maze]

Comment: Actually don't think the order of levels is necessary, I solved before seeing the edit and I think finding the pair of the emoji was a good part of the puzzle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]
>
> The maze has been escaped!

Comment: I should have made it a bit more complex! Just you wait....

Comment: @Konchog looking forward to the next :P